# View is not displayed correctly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am learning Cake now and am following [IBM's tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-cake1/section3.html). I have completed the Blog tutorial successfully from the cake site.
**My problem** is that the `Register` view does not show up. Instead of showing the form, the `register()` action is immediately performed and the condition checking whether the form's parameters are empty always fails so I always get to the failed to register user message.

---

The ctp file looks like this (it's not using the helpers):

```
<form action="/users/register" method="post">
<p>Please fill out the form below to register an account.</p>
<label>Username:</label><input name="username" size="40" />  
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" size="40" />
<label>Email Address:</label><input name="email" size="40" maxlength="255" />
<label>First Name:</label><input name="first_name" size="40" />
<label>Last Name:</label><input name="last_name" size="40" /> 
<input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
```

And the `register()` action is:

```
function register() {
    if (!empty($this->params['form']))
    {
        if ($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
        {
            $this->flash('Your registration infomration was accepted.', '/users/register');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->flash('There was a problem with your registration', '/users/register');
    }
}
```

Comment: The IMB tutorial is very old and is likely out of date for a lot of stuff.

Comment: @RichardAtHome: Currently, I am using stuff that is posted on Cake's main page. Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: The blog tutorial on the CakePHP site is a great place to start and is usually up to date with the latest version of Cake. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function register() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->flash('Your registration infomration was accepted.', '/users/register');
        } else {
            $this->flash('There was a problem with your registration', '/users/register');
        }
    }

}
```

The big difference being using `$this->data` instead of `$this->params[form]` and adding `$this->User->create();`. Also the else statement should be with if(user is saved) flash saved else flash not saved.

Comment: It seems that the fact I have the else to the primary condition kills me. When I take it out the form is displayed correcly, but if I keep it (the else to `if(!empty..`) then the resulted page is straight the else statement. Any idea? Or should I post a new question

Comment: @Ann Pham: No there is no `else` in Shaz's code and that is why it works. What I wrote is that *I* have an else in *my* code. Maybe it wasn't clear... Anyway, the `else` in the code of my question is what gave me trouble and I don't understand why.

Comment: if(form submitted){
  do this
} else(form not submitted) {
  do this
}
You didn't the controller a chance to display the form, it just went through the if/else; remember flash also acts as a redirect. You only need 
if(form submitted){
  do this
}
show form

Hope that explains a bit better?